# Will a Dole Pineapple juice can made out of tin leach the tin into the juice & cause harm?

Tags: metal, toxicity

I drink a lot of Dole Pineapple juice from the can, because it has no added sugar or ingredients. Can it be harmful because of the tin in the can? I called Dole and the can is not lined.

Answer (score 1):

No, otherwise they would get sued. If their can contained something that is toxic and leaches out, they would have legal problems galore.

Tin is very low in its toxicity, so you can eat and drink out of it and be fine. While the pineapple contains some acids, it is unlikely that they will react very vigorously with anything in the can.

As a side note, however, some "tin" cans are actually steel, which is also not very toxic.

TL;DR You are fine, enjoy your pineapple juice.